# $f(z) = u(x,y) + i\cdot v(x,y)$ holomorphic in a connected open set $D$, such that $a\cdot u(x,y)+b\cdot v(x,y)=c$, is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $f(z) = u(x,y) + i\cdot v(x,y)$ be a holomorphic function in a connected open set $D$. 
If $a\cdot u(x,y)+b\cdot v(x,y)=c$ in $D$, where $a,b,c$ are real constants which are not all zero, why $f(z)$ is constant in $D$?

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann equations. Or open mapping theorem.

Comment: It would be good to say what you tried, otherwise all we can give you are our own solutions, and we can't help you get them on your own.

Comment: Seems to me you're now posting too many questions of a very similar nature, at least one if which was false. Where are your attempts on these problems? What background do you have?

Comment: I worked through this problem, here are my hints: break down the problem for when $a=b=0$, $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$, $a\neq 0$ and $b=0$, and $a,b\neq 0$. Use the Cauchy--Riemann equations and basic algebra to get the result. It may not be the most efficient method, but it works.

Comment: Thank you @DanielFischer and Alex Schiff it was very simple!

Comment: @TedShifrin for what i know there is no limit on posting questions, and evidently my attempts are failed if i'm here to post these questions. my backgroud is a normal math' student university background. If i post questions of similar nature probably now i'm studying these arguments and i have some doubts. If is forbidden to question about these argument (also if there are some mistakes in the questions i propose) i excuse to all stackexchange.

Comment: @camascers There are limits (6 questions per 24 hours, 50 per 30 days), so it's probably wise to take a moment before posting a question and think about whether that question would make it impossible to ask a more important one later without delay. With regard to the attempts, although (obviously) failed, telling us what you attempted (not necessarily in full detail, unless you want an explanation why _that_ attempt failed, just an overview) usually gives an answerer a better starting point to know what you need explained, and possibly how.